# Parsing a phrase

Tags: parsing, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to make an algorithm to parse(i dont know if this is the correct word) a question and to get the correct answer to it.

Example

If someone ask "What is the Sun?", the correct answer would be "Is a Star"

This would be obtained from a list of phrases such as this:

"Is a Star"
"Is hot and brigth"
"I dont know"
etc

Now, I would like to know where can I get information about this,

I think the main problem here is how to make the program understand that "sun" is a star, and how to get the most accurate answer about it, becouse "Is hot and brigth" also is a valid answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is problem known as Machine Learning from Artificial Intelligence domain.
You can not just parse some phrases if you want to write good algorithm. It is not as simple as it seems to be.

You want to write your own application like http://www.cleverbot.com

I think you need to read and learn more about Machine Learning.

Comment: ok, thanks :D

Offtopic - Quite a long time since i used cleverbot last time, now it just rickrolled me D: